# NetworkError: 400 Bad Request GoogleApis / fonts / ASP.NET MVC + Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm checking my project for console errors in production server and I'm getting the below error.

"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/diploma/Content/https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700"

I suspect there is an issue with mapping the path and it should look for font files directly in 
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700"

Where would I start looking for the rootcause? I'm using Bootstrap for frontend, so perhaps there are some issues there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most noble to answer own question, but that's the only answer that I got. Basically first line of my bootstrap.css (and bootstrap.min.css) was:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700")
```

so I deleted this and instead added to _Layout.cshtml

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" type="text/css" />
```

This sorted the topic of wrong paths.